# how to use dark and light Theme in Android app

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-webview, android-theme

I just start learning the theme concept in android, but I faced a wired situation   in the app that I practice on, I tried to apply the Dark and Light mode Feature by setting the Theme programmatically when the user click on the Switch Button:

```
if (state) {
    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES)
} else {
    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO)

}
```

until this point everything work perfect, but when I tried to add a WebView in a new Fragment, each time I switch from the fragment that contain WebView to the main fragment, the UI View disturb, the colors start being unorganized and looks ugly, but when I Remove The WebView Component From the Layout everything works fine as it should!

I did a deep search on the Internet but I found nothing, I hope to give me some hint to figure out  why the WebView Component is Not Compatible with The Theme.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Hello bro this one!

```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (InitApplication.getInstance().isNightModeEnabled()) {
            AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
        } else {
            AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
        }
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        SwitchCompat switchCompat = findViewById(R.id.switchCompat);
        Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this, R.style.MyDialog)
                        .setTitle("Title")
                        .setMessage("Message")
                        .show();
            }
        });

        if (AppCompatDelegate.getDefaultNightMode() == AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES)
            switchCompat.setChecked(true);

        switchCompat.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    InitApplication.getInstance().setIsNightModeEnabled(true);
                    Intent intent = getIntent();
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                    finish();
                    startActivity(intent);

                } else {
                    InitApplication.getInstance().setIsNightModeEnabled(false);
                    Intent intent = getIntent();
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                    finish();
                    startActivity(intent);
                }


            }
        });

    }
}
```

class InitApplication

```
public class InitApplication extends Application {
    public static final String NIGHT_MODE = "NIGHT_MODE";
    private boolean isNightModeEnabled = false;

    private static InitApplication singleton = null;

    public static InitApplication getInstance() {

        if(singleton == null)
        {
            singleton = new InitApplication();
        }
        return singleton;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        singleton = this;
        SharedPreferences mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        this.isNightModeEnabled = mPrefs.getBoolean(NIGHT_MODE, false);
    }

    public boolean isNightModeEnabled() {
        return isNightModeEnabled;
    }

    public void setIsNightModeEnabled(boolean isNightModeEnabled) {
        this.isNightModeEnabled = isNightModeEnabled;

        SharedPreferences mPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPrefs.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(NIGHT_MODE, isNightModeEnabled);
        editor.apply();
    }
}
```

styles.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert"/>

    <style name="MySwitch">
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/switchColor</item>
    </style>
</resources>


<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. values-night.xml -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/orange</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/orangeDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.Dialog.Alert"/>

    <style name="MySwitch">
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/switchColor</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```